# unable to link to Sharepoint list from Ms Access

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a Sharepoint site that I cannot create an external link from within Microsoft Access 2010 to the Sharepoint site.

I enter the url to the site in the connection wizard of Ms Access  http://xxx.xxx and I get this error:
"microsoft access could not connect to the site you specified. verify the address of the site or contact your system administrator"

The address of the site is correct.  What would cause this error message?   Is there a setting in Sharepoint that needs to allow for such a connection?

I am doing this with several other Sharepoint sites at different addresses and once I enter their address, I am prompted to authenticate and can proceed to link to the lists.

What is required to make the connection available in Access?  Why would it work for very similar sites but not this one?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that we had to extend the website to include an NTLM zone accessible over a public IP.

Once that was done, I was able to connect to the Sharepoint lists from MS Access using the ntlm url.   Also needed to add alternate access mapping for the url.